# how to receive requestParam of type date(spring) from angular

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i'm newbie with **angular** and **spring**
i'm trying to send a get request with some date parameters but i keep getting an error..

- here the html code:

```
<div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label for="beforeAdmission">Avant l'Admission</label>
                <input type="text"
                   placeholder="Datepicker"
                   class="form-control"
                   id="beforeAdmission"
                   name="beforeAdmission" 
                   bsDatepicker
                   [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' }"
                   [(bsValue)]="search.beforeAdmission"
                   >
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label for="afterAdmission">Après l'Admission</label>
                <input type="text"
                   placeholder="Datepicker"
                   class="form-control"
                   id="afterAdmission"
                   name="afterAdmission" 
                   bsDatepicker
                   [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' }"
                   [(bsValue)]="search.afterAdmission"
                   >
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label for="beforePay">Avant Paiement</label>
                <input type="text"
                   placeholder="Datepicker"
                   class="form-control"
                   id="beforePay"
                   name="beforePay" 
                   bsDatepicker
                   [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' }"
                   [(bsValue)]="search.beforePay"
                   >
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label for="afterPay">Après Paiement</label>
                <input type="text"
                   placeholder="Datepicker"
                   class="form-control"
                   id="afterPay"
                   name="afterPay" 
                   bsDatepicker
                   [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' }"
                   [(bsValue)]="search.afterPay"
                   >
              </div>
             </div>
```

- here the angular **component** code:

```
export interface Search {
    beforeAdmission:Date,
    afterAdmission : Date,
    beforePay : Date,
    afterPay : Date
}
search : Search = {
        beforeAdmission:new Date(this.d.getFullYear() + 5, this.d.getMonth(), this.d.getDate()),
        afterAdmission : new Date(this.d.getFullYear() - 20 , this.d.getMonth(), this.d.getDate()),
        beforePay : new Date(this.d.getFullYear() + 5 , this.d.getMonth(), this.d.getDate()),
        afterPay :  new Date(this.d.getFullYear() - 20 , this.d.getMonth(), this.d.getDate())
}

onSearch(){

        this.service.search(this.search).subscribe(res =>{
            this.cheques = res;
        },err =>{
        
        });
    }
```

- here the angular service code

````
public search(search){
    return this.http.get(this.url+"?beforeAdmission="+search.beforeAdmission+"&afterAdmission="+search.afterAdmission
                            +"&beforePay="+search.beforePay+"&afterPay="+search.afterPay,{headers:this.headers});
    }```
````

- here the spring controller code

```
@GetMapping("/cheques")
    public Page<ChequeOrEffet> getAll(@RequestParam(name="beforeAdmission",defaultValue = "01/01/1950")@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/mm/yyyy",iso=ISO.DATE)Date beforeAdmission
                                    ,@RequestParam(name="afterAdmission",defaultValue = "01/01/2050") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/mm/yyyy",iso=ISO.DATE) Date  afterAdmission
                                    ,@RequestParam(name="beforePay",defaultValue = "01/01/1950") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/mm/yyyy",iso=ISO.DATE) Date beforePay
                                    ,@RequestParam(name="afterPay",defaultValue = "01/01/2050") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/mm/yyyy",iso=ISO.DATE) Date afterPay) {
        
        System.out.println("xx");
        return service.seach((Date)beforeAdmission, (Date)afterAdmission, (Date)beforePay, (Date)afterPay);
    }
```

- and this the the **error** i keep getting:

```
2020-08-31 01:50:45.158  WARN 35616 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date] for value 'Sun Aug 31 2025 00:00:00 GMT 0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [Sun Aug 31 2025 00:00:00 GMT 0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)]]
```

ps: i already tried some solutions from stackoverflow but nothing worked for me,

Comment: From the logs, looks like you are sending the JS Dates as its `toString()` rather than in the expected pattern that you have defined in `@DateTimeFormat`. Please share your Angular service and component code.

Comment: @drumonii i edited the code and added the angular component + service
thanks for your note

Answer (score 0):

In your Angular service, you are sending the dates of your `Search` as their `toString()` representation. But in your Spring controller, you are expecting them to be in "dd/mm/yyyy" format. Spring cannot parse your those date strings into a `Date`, hence the `IllegalArgumentException`.

You can format the JS dates into "dd/mm/yyyy" in your Angular service. For example using a simple method like:

```
formatDate(date: Date): string {
  const day = date.getDate() < 10 ? `0${date.getDate()}` : date.getDate() + '';
  const month = date.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? `0${date.getMonth() + 1}` : (date.getMonth() + 1) + '';
  const year = date.getFullYear() + '';
  return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
}
```

Or use a date library like https://date-fns.org/ for more robust formatting.

Then use the `formatDate` method in your service:

```
public search(search) {
  const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('beforeAdmission', formatDate(search.beforeAdmission))
    .set('afterAdmission', formatDate(search.afterAdmission))
    .set('beforePay', formatDate(search.beforePay))
    .set('afterPay', formatDate(search.afterPay));

  const options = {
    params,
    headers: this.headers
  };
  return this.http.get(this.url, options);
}
```

Finally, you need to set the `pattern` of `@DateTimeFormat` to be correct (`mm` is minute of hour).

```
@GetMapping("/cheques")
public ResponseEntity<String> getAll(
            @RequestParam(name = "beforeAdmission", defaultValue = "01/01/1950") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy") Date beforeAdmission,
            @RequestParam(name = "afterAdmission", defaultValue = "01/01/2050") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy") Date afterAdmission,
            @RequestParam(name = "beforePay", defaultValue = "01/01/1950") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy") Date beforePay,
            @RequestParam(name = "afterPay", defaultValue = "01/01/2050") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy") Date afterPay) {
        
        System.out.println("xx");
        return service.seach((Date) beforeAdmission, (Date) afterAdmission, (Date) beforePay, (Date) afterPay);
    }
```

I would also suggest using `java.time.LocalDate` over `java.util.Date`.